# How to mock classA object which is created in classB?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I have something as,

```
classB {
    classA a = new classA();
    ...
}

classA {
    ...
}
```

I would like to write junit on classB. How to mock object a of classA?

Comment: One should not create `A` within `B`'s constructor and instead use [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control#:~:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20inversion%20of,control%20from%20a%20generic%20framework.) to pass an instance of `A` to `B`'s constructor. The only other way that comes to my mind is using powermock, but this messes with the bytecode and thus cann screw up JaCoCo Code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the A in as a parameter to the constructor of B.